IOS 17.4.1 safari extension issues
Since updating to iOS v17.4.1 our safari extension no longer functions as it used to We are experiencing issues where our content script is not getting initialized, On devices running iOS 17.4.1, the content script included in our extension does not appear to run. There are no logs from the content script in the console, whereas on other versions and devices, it operates as expected. Our Extension relies con communication between the background and content scripts in order for us to render various popups to our users, based on our logs as of iOS 17.4.1 this communication is not successful, we can see messages being sent from the background script but as mentioned above nothing on the content script side.
This behavior happens majority of the time and on random sites, sometimes opening the same site in a new tab would work but not always. There are also times where we would only receive our popups after opening the safari menu and interacting with our extension via this menu.
Any assistance will be welcomed
Tried creating a simple extension with very basic functionality to test and make sure that it is indeed the ios version that is the issue and our specific extension

Same here. Have you been able to gather more information? Luckily seems to be fixed on iOS 17.5 beta.

Same here. Still works in 17.0, but are you sure about 17.5.? @DeveloBär?
